# Wrong note by playing G on my Ibanez

Tags: strings, semi-acoustic-guitar

i Play a Ibanez Artcore guitar. If I put my tuner on my  guitar and I play a tone on the bass string, like G on the E string,  the Display mean to high... It is between G and G# in comparison to a Piano you can hear the difference. Could there bei a Problem with the Strings (010-046). Does someone was faced to a similare problem?

Comment: Only the G, or anything fretted on that string? Did you check the intonation at the octave?

Comment: You should clarify your question. Are you saying the open E is tune according to the tuner but the fretted G is not? Or are you saying that both are in tune according to the tuner but sound out of tune compared to the piano? If it's the latter, then it sounds like your *piano* isn't in tune.

Comment: Basics first: Is the open E actually in tune (or is it also between E en E#/F)? 
In any case: The amount of string related tuning problems during 40 years of playing are virtually zero, so I would say: No, not string related. Neck related problems usually don't start out at the 3rd fret either. I'm guessing that (a) the open E string is not in tune either, or (b) you're not playing a clean note, either by bending it slightly or vibrating it slightly (parallel to the neck),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First task is to check the intonation by playing the 12th fret note fretted, and comparing it with the harmonic there. if they aren't the same, exactly, then the bridge or saddles need moving until they are.

You'll probably find that the G is in tune then, assuming the open string itself is in tune first. If this doesn't work, it may be that the neck relief is too much, and the string is being bent sharp when fretted.

Comment: The Bridge on the top was too high, now it works. 12th fret perfect E and fifth perfect A. All the otheres are also perfect! Thank you!